# Change UIButton image to another UIButton image view

Tags: swift, class

As the title, my question is how I can change one UIButton's image to a other UIButton's image? Is it possible to get a current image from a UIButton's image? I already used the Tag option, but that Tag option is to store an Int value. I heard something about classes and subclasses but I could not figure that out.

In my code I have 8 cards. These cards are all just UIButton's. When the user clicks Go, those 8 cards will be randomly picked from an array which contains the image names, and a tag will be added. The tag is a Int, which contains the value of the card.

Of these 8 cards, 1 card is the master card, and the 7 other cards, are random cards. When the user clicks on 1 card, the master card must be replaced with the card the user pressed. This is where I am confusing myself. How can I solve this? Ofcourse, the tag must be also replaced.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code that you have written? It's hard to answer this question in the abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
firstButton.setImage(secondButton.imageView!.image, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: You just saved my day, MVP.

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please accept it? Thanks!